# How to wrap words in quotes with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Specifically, I'd like to wrap many individual words in their own quotes, if that's possible? I know this has been asked before but frankly I do not understand the answers since I'm no coder or regular user of N++. So if it could be explained like I'm a 2-year old it would be appreciated lol.

Comment: Please include the sample text you need to modify.  We can't help you without seeing this.

Comment: It's just random names, separated by commas like this.

Tony, Paul, Eric, Sarah

Comment: This might be beyond the ability of NPP, at least beyond the ability of regex.

Comment: ah ok. Worth asking at least.

Comment: Is the desired output of 
Tony, Paul, Eric, Sarah this:
"Tony", "Paul", "Eric", "Sarah"?

Comment: @LarsFischer yes

Comment: @MickandLee Then it can be done with an Regex, use the Replace Dialog, tick "Regular Expression at the bottom left, use `([^, ]+)` as Find what and `"\1"` as Replace with. Click Replace All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!")\b\w+\b(?!")`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!")          # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't quote before the word
\b              # word boundary
\w+             # 1 or more word character
\b              # word boundary
(?!")           # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't quote after the word
```

**Replacement:**

```
"       # a double quote
$0      # the whole match (i.e. the word)
"       # a double quote
```

**Given:**

```
 Tony, Paul, Eric, Sarah, "Tony", "Paul", "Eric", "Sarah"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
 "Tony", "Paul", "Eric", "Sarah", "Tony", "Paul", "Eric", "Sarah"
```